# Derived Entities in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, derived

I have inherited a project in which the original designer used the same database table for two logically distinct entities (root level details and also their sub-details which are subtly different).

I would like to derive two new entities from the existing entity so that I can make them distinct in the code (each have logically orthogonal properties and collections which are linked without referential integrity).

The two new derived classes will have no rows of their own, and no physical table to map to. I can add the derived Entities in the EF model, and it will build, but it can't run because it wants to map the derived entities to some table.

Any idea how to get this model to work?

Comment: provide a simplified version of your tables. Are you using Code-First or Database-First?

Comment: Database first. I have an Order table that references its LineItems and those LineItems have child LineItems that are the same data type in the database but are logically different. The parent child relationship comes through a column in the table the references the line number of its parent.